# Вёрстка Div

Tags: css

Доброго времени суток! Уважаемые веб-дизайнеры, подскажите, пожалуйста, как верстать сайт div'ами. Мне нужно три блока друг под другом. Блоки шириной во всю страницу. Как это сделать? Если напишете код, буду очень признателен!

Comment: @prog, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Не сочтите за рекламу, но я хочу сделать что-то подобное: http://redhelper.ru/
У меня почему-то блоки такие не растягиваются на всю страницу, и, вообще, я плохо понимаю в div-вёрстке.

Comment: @prog, прочитайте комментарий выше вашего.

Comment: Ну, вот код:

    html, body {
    margin:0;height:100%;
    }
    #wrapper {
    height:auto !important;height:100%;min-height:100%;min- width:800px;               
    }
    #header {
    height:200px;
    } 
    .clear {
    clear:both;
    }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```